# How are cookie queries handled on Read the Docs?

Tags: cookies, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, data-protection

How are cookie queries handled on Read the Docs?

Currently, Google Analytics can be used for Read the Docs documentation. However, a cookie is set for this. In order for this to be compliant with the DSVGO/GDPR (European Data Protection Act), a cookie query must be introduced, e.g. by means of a cookie banner. The question that now arises is how such a banner can be implemented on a Read the Docs documentation, or whether this is possible at all? Are there any plugins or extensions to use? The documentation was written in reST using the Sphinx documentation generator.

Comment: I suggest you contact RTD at privacy@readthedocs.org. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/privacy-policy.html and https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/legal/dpa/index.html

Comment: @StevePiercy I did this recently - the reply was not exactly helpful. Essentially, I was pointed [here](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/legal/index.html?highlight=gdpr).

Comment: Currently, the response from read-the-docs that i received was that no solution is available, but they are investigating a solution so that a cookie banner can be added.